# Duplicate checking with like operator

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to check duplicate values in my table with `like` operator:

```
select F_Barcode, COUNT(*) as cnt
from T_Assets 
group by F_Barcode
having COUNT(*) > 1
```

This is working fine, but some of my barcode duplicated is like this

```
4456   
00004456
```

and

```
45552
00045552
```

Actually this is the same barcode, but duplicated.

I need to see all of my barcodes duplicated like this? How I can do that?

```
F_Barcode datatype nvarchar(50).
```

Values like `0000frdz` can't be converted to data type int.

Comment: Try converting the values to integer, so that the zero would be truncated. But this only works if your data is string but only contains numbers.

Comment: You should have accepted @juergen-d's answer because that was correct based on the information you have given in your question. Your comment should really have been in your original question.

Comment: Still @void's answer is correct for the question you have posted. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Define the rule that makes a barcode. You say '4456' shall be considered equal to '00004456'. What about barcodes containing letters? Is 'A' the same as '0A'? Is 'A' the same as 'a'? Is 'A001B' the same as 'A1B'? Can there be leading or trailing blanks? How would they be considered? Plese give us the full picture.

Answer (score 1):

You can cast the type of barcode to integer, then do the count ops.
Just like this:

```
select F_Barcode,COUNT(*) as cnt  From T_Assets 
group by CAST(F_Barcode AS UNSIGNED) having COUNT(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Check This.

Using Substring:

```
          select substring(F_Barcode, patindex('%[^0]%',F_Barcode), 100),
          COUNT(*) as cnt             
          From T_Assets 
          group by substring(F_Barcode, patindex('%[^0]%',F_Barcode), 100) 
          having COUNT(*) > 1 

          --- Replace 100 with datatype size
```

Using Cast :

```
          select CAST(F_Barcode as int),COUNT(*) as cnt  
          From F_Barcode 
          group by CAST(F_Barcode as int)
          having COUNT(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

1. fix a length for string.
2. add O's in the beginning to match desired length.
3. then collect count group wise.

   select RIGHT('000000000'+F_Barcode,9) as F_Barcode, COUNT(*) as cnt
   from T_Assets 
   group by RIGHT('000000000'+F_Barcode,9)
   having COUNT(*) > 1

Here I have considered string length to 9. You can adjust as per your requirement.
Please take a note that you have to add equal number of 0's to your string length at beginning of you column.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution for SQL Server 2012 or above is to use `TRY_CONVERT` to ensure that cast will never fail. Barcodes should contain numbers only, but since you are storing them in a `NVARCHAR` field

**Setup**

```
create table BarcodeData
(
    F_Barcode NVARCHAR(50)
)

insert into BarcodeData VALUES ('4456'), ('00004456'), ('45552'), ('00045552'), ('a45552'), ('1234'), ('0'), ('00001'), ('a45552')
GO
```

**Query**

```
;WITH CleanedBarcode AS (
    -- CAST is required because INT type is inferred and will generate failure when a non number is met
    SELECT ISNULL(CAST(TRY_CONVERT(INT, F_Barcode) AS NVARCHAR(50)), F_Barcode) AS CleanedCode
    FROM BarcodeData
)
SELECT *
FROM CleanedBarcode CB
GROUP BY CB.CleanedCode
HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
```